# ViewControllers dont get removed from scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c

My project is using ARC and objective c. And i'm having troubles with the

ViewControllers  that is created inside my scrollview. They dont get removed
   completely.

What i did was that i have created a **UIScrollView** inside the main 
     ViewController. Then i have created 2 other ViewControllers.

I'm placing the 2 viewControllers inside the UIScrollView like that:

```
 ViewController1 * test1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];

 ViewController2 * test1 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];

 [scrollview addSubview:test1.view];

 [scrollview addSubview:test2.view];
```

it works and i can see both of my design from the viewControllers. But when i try to remove both viewControllers from the main viewController and add them back later it create new views, but the same old views still exist underneath. I want to completely remove them from the main viewController and create new ones instead.

i'm removing them like that:

```
[test1 removeFromParentViewController];
[test2 removeFromParentViewController];


[test1.view removeFromSuperview];
[test2.view removeFromSuperview];
```

The code where i'm adding new views for the second time is like the first one, but here it is:

```
 ViewController1 * test1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];

 ViewController2 * test1 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];

 [scrollview addSubview:test1.view];

 [scrollview addSubview:test2.view];
```

but i'm only doing this when the remove is done.

**FIXED IT**:

The problem was that i was using block-based notification handlers which sometimes stops the app from calling dealloc to release my viewcontrollers. I tested that anything that use block-based stuff will kind block the app from calling dealloc the fix is to stop/free the  block-based notification and then make a remove call of the views.

Comment: Could you post the code where you are adding new views for the second time?

Comment: Sure, but i'm just calling again the same when the remove is done: ViewController1 * test1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];

 ViewController2 * test1 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];

 [scrollview addSubview:test1.view];

 [scrollview addSubview:test2.view];

Comment: Could you zip up your project and upload it to dropbox or something?  I am bored this afternoon, and wouldn't mind taking a gander.

It sounds like you need to make more than 1 change

Comment: i think when you want to removeFromSupperView you object  test1 & test2 is nill !!!!!

Comment: A O i would love to, but there many files so it kinda hard to go and edit.. i really dont understand why it still overlap... sense i can see that all view go away, but still there..

Comment: just checked no they are not nill...

Comment: If you go in Finder, find the folder that contains your `.xcproj`.  Right click it, and choose "Compress xxxxx"  Then upload that .zip

Comment: I have fixed it by myself. But thanks for all the help and support :) !

Comment: If you fixed it yourself, you should post an answer to this question. That way others can learn from you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT:

The problem was that i was using block-based notification handlers which sometimes stops the app from calling dealloc to release my viewcontrollers. I tested that anything that use block-based stuff will kind block the app from calling dealloc the fix is to stop/free the  block-based notification and then make a remove call of the views.

Comment: To improve both the answer and the question, please add the actual code that causes the problem and the revisions that resolve the issue. Doing that would allow me to vote up both. The explanation is not bad but code makes the problem more specific and the solution more meaningful. Also if there is an error please point out the line in the code where the error is generated. Welcome to the site.